# Which Test to check relationship between age (continuous independent variable) and multi nominal variable (type of topography- Dependent Variable)

Tags: machine-learning, independence

I have two variables,

- Age variable - continuous (**Independent variable**)
- Topography type - (7 categories), multinomial variable (**Dependent variable**)

(Topography variable is related to cancer data, C500-C509)

How can I check the independence of these two variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible options: (1) check if the units in the seven topography groups have different distributions by parametric or nonparametric anova (2) bin the age variable in classes and then apply a chi-squared test. Is any of this what you are looking for?